# how to convert ArcGIS raster layers into .grd files and upload into R?

Tags: raster, rgdal

I am trying to create background data points in R as part of a species distribution modelling project. I cannot figure out how to convert my environmental predictor raster layers (annual precipitation, mean summer temperatures, etc.) into .grd files so that I can read them into R. Are there some basic steps to follow to convert Raster data into .grd files?

Answer (score 1):

There is really no need to save files in that format. Almost any format can be used, except the ESRI geodatabase. It might be that your files already are in a usable format (e.g. tif, img, esri grid). See what happens when you use `raster(filename)`. Otherwise export to GTiff.